# tfe.implicit_values_and_gradients with additional outputs

Tags: tensorflow

The easy way to get gradients in TensorFlow eager mode is

```
@tfe.implicit_value_and_gradients
def loss_fn(data):
  output = network(data)
  loss = f(output)
  return loss

...
loss, grads = loss_fn(data)
```

What do I do if I want to compute extra data at the same time, such as `accuracy` along with `loss`?  I.e., I want something like

```
@tfe.implicit_values_and_gradients_of_first_result
def compute_fn(data):
  output = network(data)
  loss = f(output)
  accuracy = g(output)
  return loss, accuracy

...
loss, accuracy, loss_grads = compute_fn(data)
```

I could mock this up myself by stuffing the `accuracy` value into a separate state variable.  Is that the best way to do it, or is there an existing convenience function that makes this easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such cases, you're better off using the [`GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/GradientTape) interface. So something like:

```
def compute_fn(data):
  with tfe.GradientTape() as tape:
    output = network(data)
    loss = f(output)
  accuracy = g(output)
  return loss, accuracy, tape.gradients(loss, network.variables)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  Should accuracy be computed outside of the with, or does it matter?

Comment: Ah, good point. Doing it outside the with will be better as you won't pay the overheads of recording the operations in `g` to allow for back propagation through them (which you don't seem to need) (edited answer)